# User specific session crash (Java Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, crash, timeout

I have a Spring MVC project in Java. This web app can be accessed by multiple users in different browsers. I haven't coded any session bean in my program.

Now I want to 'crash'/'timeout' the browsing of one of the users, while other users will go on with their normal expected browsing. I want to do this to see if this action has any effect on the shared variables.

What kind of coding I need to do for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How will you recognize for which user to 'crash'/'timeout' the browsing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve here, but I'm assuming that you are doing this as an experiment ... to see what happens.

You could modify the webapp to implement some special request, or request parameter, or request parameter value that tells the webapp to crash or freeze the request being processed.  Then send that request from one browser while others are doing "normal" things.

Whether this is going to reveal anything interesting is ... questionable.

---

Another interpretation is that you are aiming to include timed out requests and other things in your normal testing regime.  To achieve that, you would need implement some kind of test harness to automate the sending of requests to your server; i.e. to *simulate* a number of simultaneous users doing things.  There are various test tools for doing that kind of thing.